# Odoo use id of just created record

Tags: odoo

I need to create company and right away create contact that bound to that company:

```
vals = {...}
company = self.env['res.partner'].create(vals)
vals = {'company_id': company.id, ...}
contact = self.env['res.partner'].create(vals)
```

But odoo says: DETAIL:  Key (company_id)=(49) is not present in table "res_company".

Transaction is not commited yet (as i suppose).
So how can i use field of just created records?

Method launched in ir.cron:

Method called like this:

```
<record model="ir.cron" id="ir_cron_load_data">
    <field name="name">Load</field>
    <field eval="False" name="active" />
    <field name="interval_number">24</field>
    <field name="interval_type">hours</field>
    <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
    <field name="priority">100</field>
    <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
    <field name="model" eval="'sap_contacts'"/>
    <field name="function" eval="'action_load_data'"/>
    <field name="args" eval="'()'"/>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vals = {...}
company = self.env['res.partner'].create(vals)
vals = {'company_id': company.id, ...}
contact = self.env['res.partner'].create(vals)
```

The company_id field is a relational field between the `res_partner` and `res_company` tables. You try to create a record on the `res_partner` using the vals, the vals has a company_id key that has a company.id as its value. The company.id that you have there is the id of the new record you created on the `res.partner` table.

You have to create the company in the `res.company` table:

company = `self.env['res.company'].create(some_vals)`

and then get the id of that company `company.id`